# Google Oauth: Added a new redirect_uri, getting "The app is blocked" error on the new subdomain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

My app runs on multiple subdomains
i.e. `abc.foo.com` `xyz.foo.com` for different regions.

We recently created a PWA for our app which runs on a different subdomain
`m-abc.foo.com` `m-xyz.foo.com`

To enable `Sign in with Google` for the PWAs, I added the redirect_uris and Authorized origins in the API Credentials for Google Cloud Platform.

Now, for these new subdomains I am getting the following error on the consent screen after choosing the google email address

```
This app is blocked 
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.
```

The app currently asks for read/write access for Calendar only.

Could not find anything definitive on support documents either.
Anybody has any idea what I might be missing here?

To check, I added another subdomain `def.foo.com` and added redirect_uri for it. This time Google Signin worked fine without problem.
Does this have anything to do with the apps being a PWA?

Thanks!

Comment: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en

Comment: @JohnHanley The app is verified already.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Updating the question with more details. @JohnHanley

Comment: This is not a redirect uri error message.   Are you sure the issue is with the redirect uri?  Where are you seeing this error? is it in the consent popup flow?   Is this app  by change using gmail and the *Less secure apps*  feature?   Are you using google workspace?